# Is there a way to "end" an org tree so that the text afterwards is at the top level?

Tags: org-mode

Sometimes, I'd like to have a way to indicate that an org tree has an "end" and then be able to return to the top level. I.e. I'd like the document to look like this:

```
* headline

  some text here

  more text

  END-OUTLINE

Text here is at the top-level and is not indented.

* another headline

  text

  END-OUTLINE

More top-level text.
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use [plain list](https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html) syntax instead of [headlines](https://orgmode.org/manual/Headlines.html) syntax

- By definition the body of headlines will always include content after the headline up to the next headline. Once content is placed under a headline there is not a way to designate that the content should be part of the top level again.

  ```
  This paragraph will always be outside of headline.

  * Headline A
  This paragraph will always be under Headline A.

  ** Headline B
  This paragraph will always be under Headline B.

  * Headline C
  This paragraph will always be under Headline C.


  This paragraph will always be under Headline C too.
  ```
- In contrast, the content of plain lists is determined by the indentation level or if there are 2 blank/empty lines in the list.

  ```
  This paragraph will always be outside of Lists.

  - List Item A

    This paragraph will always be under List Item A.

    - List Item B

      This paragraph will always be under List Item A and List Item B.

    This paragraph will always be under List Item A.


  1. List Item C

     This paragraph will always be under List Item C.

  2. List Item D

     This paragraph will always be under List Item D.

  This paragraph will always be outside of Lists.
  ```

---

> **TIP:** There are builtin functions to switch between plain lists and headlines. These conversion functions provide a convenient method to switch back and forth while typing.
>
> - To convert headline to plain list, Place cursor on headline and type <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>.
> - To convert plain list to headline, place cursor on list item and type <kbd>C- c</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>.

---

> **Note:** This answer was tested using:
>
> ---
>
> emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1
>   org-mode version:  9.1.2

Comment: Hmm... Interesting approach! I'll see if I can get used to that. :-)

Comment: @dharmatech - Thanks! There are builtin functions to switch between plain lists and headlines. Place cursor on headline and type `C-c` `-` to convert headline to plain list. To convert plain list to headline place cursor on list item and type `C-` `*`.  These conversion functions make it easy to switch back and forth as you type.